# Trouble utilizing Webpack externals

Tags: webpack, commonjs, es6-modules

I'm creating a library that depends on Styled-Components.  I'm also making an app that depends on my library and Styled-Components.  Doing nothing special, I got a warning about two instances of Styled-Components being loaded.  After some researching, it seemed that I needed to use webpack externals so as to not compile Styled-Components into my library bundle.

My first question is do I also need to utilize npm's peer dependencies?  Is this an orthogonal concept?  Anyway, I also added Styled-Components as a peer dependency of my library.

My host app was having lots of problems.  So I create a simplified demo app (will post all this to repo's if required).  It's just an index.js file that imports my library.  I also then npm install Styled-Components.  I'm using es6 syntax to import my library and so I add all the obligatory babel packages.  I setup my webpack config to bundle my app.

But I get this error:

> ERROR in ../libs/ab-chart/dist/bundle.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'styled-components' in
>   '/Users/abollba/Dropbox/all/web/apps/libs/ab-chart/dist'

I've poured over the webpack documentation for hours.  I've built, torn down and experimented with every config key endlessly.  I am at a point where I'm about to give up.  There's just too many factors and confusing errors to know what to even do.  I'd tremendously appreciate any help!

### Edit (more information):

providing information requested in answers:

1) [libraries webpack config](https://gist.github.com/AlexanderBollbach/989a0fa8c950ccdffe09335c6ff5b40c)

2) [library package.json](https://gist.github.com/AlexanderBollbach/c48595c7b147d607aa82a0fa8ba4e214)

3) i include the library in my app like this: `import { Chart } from "ab-chart";`

4) [package.json for host app](https://gist.github.com/AlexanderBollbach/522af9c80131a80047ebe8242c305995)

5) [webpack config for host app](https://gist.github.com/AlexanderBollbach/1bb4cc8fde2e423071c3d26b67d7d1c7)

Comment: Can you add a bit more details to your questions? In particular: 1. the webpack config you use in your library 2. the package.json for your library 3. how you include the library in the app 4. the package.json for the app 5. the webpack config for the app — this will help people figure out what's going on

Comment: In particular, I am interested about where you import the library from, in your app. Is it from a folder _outside_ your app folder? If so, webpack may not be able to resolve your module.

Comment: note that i've replaced my real app real a test app thats just a bare bones webpack project.  but this still exhibits the unresolved Styled-Components module importing, which is good.  i've add the pieces of information you asked for. @Dan

Comment: and as per my EDIT - 3) . i'm importing my library in my entry file w/ ES6 module syntax.

Comment: Can you try using resolve.symlinks = false in your host app webpack config? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-symlinks

Comment: added it.  same error.